# Unbearable slow with high-end built desktop

Tags: linux, hard-drive, performance, nvme, amd-ryzen

I have a recent build with an ASUS Pro WS WRX80E-SAGE SE Motherboard, AMD Ryzen Threadripper PRO 5975WX Processor, 512GB of RAM, and 4TB NVME Sabrent Rocket 4 Plus, but it is unbearably slow.

My current setup is just a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 on the desktop and all default settings in the BIOS (with the latest version 1003). At the moment I only installed R runtime to troubleshoot the slowness. When I don't run anything, the command `hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1` outputs:

```
# hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1
Timing buffered disk reads: 8386 MB in  3.00 seconds = 2795.01 MB/sec
```

And many times would be > `3000 MB/sec`.

Once I start running some codes, for example (in R):

```
sim_calculations <- function() {
   x <- rnorm(1)
   y <- rnorm(1)
   x^2 + y^2
}
tmp <- replicate(10000000, sim_calculations())
```

the whole system is so laggy that it is unusable. I don't have any graphics card or monitor hooked up, just ssh to the IP of the machine to run the code from the terminal.

```
# hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1
Timing buffered disk reads:  20 MB in  3.04 seconds = 6.57 MB/sec
```

`sensors` command shows that nvme and CPU temperatures are around `40` celsius.
`htop` shows only a single core is used with 100% utilization.
`iostat -d 10` shows:

```
Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
...
nvme0n1          12.40         0.00        63.20         0.00          0        632          
...
```

Once I kill that R process, `hdparm` goes back to high speed again in a couple of seconds.

I also tried to install Windows 11, and the same thing happened, I couldn't even pass through the driver installation cause the whole machine just hang and I had to reset it, even though (I remembered) the task manager show all CPU, RAM, and Disk Use < 10%.

What could be the problem that cause this to happen?

Comment: How does the new system run from a USB bootable OS, e.g., Ubuntu or WinRE (AKA WinPE)? These are usually temporarily in RAM, rather than relying on constant drive I/O, so might help isolate the issue (e.g., drive problems).

Comment: I just used a live USB with ubuntu and the problem remains, i.e., `hdparm -t /dev/nvme0n1` is fast when nothing is running but is extremely slow when the R code above is executed.

Comment: @bya have you tried running `hdparm -t` test on a USB drive instead and see if there's any significant drop? (Normally you should be able to get ~80MB/s seq read speed from some dirt-cheap SanDisk thumb drive, since it drops to 20MB/s for the NVMe case, I suppose the drop would still be observable if it is there, i.e. non-nvme-specific)

Comment: So this code, is just to demonstrate, right? Other trivial taks bring down system to a crawl as well? I'd start by excluding stuff, so run with I dunno, 16 GB RAM, etc..

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have a similar situation with almost the same setup.

Comment: @user3037237 I never solved this unfortunately. This machine was built as a workstation in a lab and shortly after that I graduated so I am not sure how it was taken care of :(